# Creating Year/Consumption Chart with Disconnected Table Issue

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

_Hi, I want to create a Year/Consumption chart that returns the consumption for years less than or equal to the year selected by the slicer.
I think it's necessary to establish a disconnected table, but I'm stuck on the query (the result of my measure is the same for all desired years)
My data entries :
•   DateTable with date granularity and a Year Column
•   measure [conso]
•   a slicer which returns a selected value (DateTable[year])
Thanks in advance for your help
[Here is my Pbix file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv9Az6QI2uF6Rd7qkE?e=Ybe1Pi)

Comment: I succeeded with a table and a disconnected year table, but not with a chart...

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: When i select a year with my DateTable[year] slicer, i Want the chart to display only the years equals to or under the selected year, along with their associated datas.

Comment: This video might be what you're looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8Rm7dwM6gc&t=2s

Comment: Many Thanks Davide, It works perfectly. I will have a closer look to that master !

Comment: Hi Davide, could you vote this post solved ? Thanks in advance.